# Long click on buttons

Tags: android, button

I am creating an Android app to control the mouse of my PC. The application has 4 buttons (left, right, up, down). On clicking on them the application sends an integer to pc, the Java application running on PC will receive it and moves the cursor.

Now all I want to do is when user press a button for long time, the application has to send the number continuously to pc until user releases the button. Someone please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to listen for [MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN) and when it happens start sending appropriate signal to computer for example each 0.5 seconds. Stop doing this after `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

private TextView TV;
private Thread move_curser;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV1);
    TV.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    boolean isPressed = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
    boolean isReleased = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;

    if(isPressed) {
        move_curser = new Thread(new move_curser());
        move_curser.start();
        your_methode();
        return true;

    } else if(isReleased){
        move_curser.interrupt();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public class move_curser implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        int time = 500;



        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            interrupt();
        }
        while(true){
            your_methode();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                interrupt();
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: i tried this kind of code before. the problem is that isPressed is true all the time and the app will crash.

Comment: @ Anoopss Golden
I think then you have to work with a new Thread..
does the interrupt() method works for you..?

Comment: it also didnt work for me... cursor is still moving indefinitely.... it wont stop even after the button is released.